# How to get all foursquare venues from a specific owner?

Tags: search, foursquare

I'm able to search for venues using different criteria (latitude, longitude, some query) using https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search (+ parameters). But I want to retrieve all venues owned by a specific user (I have auth token for him).

How can I get a list of all venues owned by a specific owner?
Is there any specific parameter to specify the userid of the owner?

I searched their documentation but haven't found anything.

Will appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need the foursquare merchant API:

https://developer.foursquare.com/merchant/index_docs.html

Using this API you can get a list of venues managed by a particular user.

Comment: So what is the exact call you are making in order to get the venues managed by a specific user?